# Create new row entry that is sum of selected rows in R

Tags: r

apologies in advance if this has already been asked... I found it difficult to phrase the question just to ask here, much less search for!

This is a smaller example of the type of data I am working with:

```
> df <- data.frame("ID"=c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A3","A3","A3","A3"), 
             "Cat"=c("corn","wheat","quarry","barley","corn","wheat","lake","corn","wheat","quarry","rye"), 
             "Count"=c(3,1,3,4,5,2,4,7,2,9,1))

> df
   ID    Cat Count
1  A1   corn     3
2  A1  wheat     1
3  A1 quarry     3
4  A1 barley     4
5  A2   corn     5
6  A2  wheat     2
7  A2   lake     4
8  A3   corn     7
9  A3  wheat     2
10 A3 quarry     9
11 A3    rye     1
```

I have several hundred different IDs, each of which have a count entry for about two dozen different category types. Not every ID will have an entry for each category. What I would like to do is to create a new category type that sums up a selection of other categories for each unique ID. For example, this would be the output from the above data:

```
  ID    Cat Count
1 A1  crops     8
2 A1 quarry     3
3 A2  crops     7
4 A2   lake     4
5 A3  crops    10
6 A3 quarry     9
```

...if I wanted to add together corn, wheat, barley, and rye into a new category, "crops", but exclude quarry and lake.

I have successfully used "aggregate" to produce this data frame in the first place, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to create an entirely new row made by the summation of several rows, all within one ID number.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Can you check the output of the last row?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`).  Assign the "Cat" to "crops" for elements that not 'quarry' or 'lake', then grouped by "Cat" and "ID", we get the `sum` of "Count".

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!(Cat %chin% c("quarry", "lake")), Cat := "crops"]
df[, .(Count=sum(Count)),.(ID, Cat)]
#    ID    Cat Count
#1: A1  crops     8
#2: A1 quarry     3
#3: A2  crops     7
#4: A2   lake     4
#5: A3  crops    10
#6: A3 quarry     9
```

---

Or using `base R`, we `transform` the dataset by `replace`ing the elements that are not "quarry" or "lake" with "crops", and then `aggregate` to get the `sum` of "Count" grouped by "Cat" and "ID".

```
df1 <- transform(df, Cat = replace(as.character(Cat), 
      !(Cat %in% c("quarry", "lake")), "crops"))
aggregate(Count~., df1, sum)
```